# Sunspot: where to put my Model.search code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, decorator, code-organization, sunspot

I defined my User model as searchable:

```
class User < ActiveRecord:Base
    searchable do
        #...
    end
end
```

Now, I'm wondering what's the best place to actually have the search call:

```
User.search do
    keywords kw
    # insert a toooon of with, facets etc...
end
```

I don't want to have this huge block in the controller.
I'm using [draper](https://github.com/jcasimir/draper) (implement the decorator pattern), but it's really coupled to a model, so I don't think it's the best place. Or is it?

Should I just create a Search class and do something like

```
@search = Search::UserSearch(params)
```

in the controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd encourage you to put this in Search::UserSearch class. It always a good idea to separate concerns and follow single responsibility principle.

You can put this class in

> app/models/search/user_search.rb

(don't forget to add search dir to autoload paths)

Nevertheless I'm doing this in one of my project and I'm happy with it.

Comment: Ok then, I'll make a class. I dont think I will put it in app/models though. If I decided to save each search, that's where I'd put it, but I think in this case, it would be better in lib?

Answer (score 1):

Putting search logic into separarate class is the best idea. It follows the idea of skinny controllers, search class will be reusable in your app and it is easy to test.